# Jquery após reload

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de fazer, pois tenho uma função que quando clico em um botão do menu ele captura via jquery a id da pagina porem se exemplo eu estiver na pagina INICIO que nao tem id e for para pagina serviço que tem ID ele da um reload e minha ação não funciona tem alguma maneira seila armazenamento nos coookies seila ?

```
 $('.sub-menu a').click(function() {

        var anchor;
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        if (link.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
            anchor = '#' + link.split('#').pop();
            console.log('anchor',anchor);
        }

        $('.id-sub').slideUp(2000);
        if (anchor !== undefined) {
            $(anchor).slideDown(2000).addClass('fixed');       
            $('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': $(anchor) }, 600, function(){
                window.location.hash = target;
            })
        }
    });
```

porque seguinte preciso esconder todos os conteudos que estao na class `('.id-sub')` mais quando eu saiu da pagina INICIO e clico na pagina SERVIÇO ele tinha que me mostrar somente a ID que eu cliquei e esconder o resto do conteudo mais como a pagina da reload ele esconde tudo e nao mostra a id que eu cliquei

Comment: Indique o que pretende fazer, ou seja, a funcionalidade que pretende implmentar.

Comment: assim tenho um menu que contem `INICIO` e `SERVIÇOS (com sub-menus)` cada sub-menus desses tem uma determinada `ID` quando eu estou na pagina INICIO e quero passar para a pagina SERVIÇO ele tem que ver a id que eu cliquei que a função acima já faz mostrar a id correta e esconder as outras pois se esse conteudo esta em uma pagina só

Comment: se eu estiver ja dentro da pagina `SERVIÇO` e clicar nas `id` ele funciona normalmente porém quando eu estou na pagina `INICIO` e clico em um `sub-menu` ele mostra todo o conteudo daquela pagina sendo que era para mostrar somente o conteudo da `id` clicada

Comment: deu para entender um pouco?

Comment: Lamento mas não consigo entender o propósito

Comment: tenho um `MENU` este menu tem `INICIO` e `SERVIÇO (com sub-menus de cada serviço)` se eu estiver na pagina menu e clicar nos sub-menus ele da um efeito de sliderUP e slideDown conforme a `id` que for clicada do sub-menu porém se eu estiver na pagina `INICIO`  e clicar em uma `id` do sub-menu ele teria que mostrar somente o conteudo da `id` que eu cliquei certo mais isso nao acontece ele simplesmente da reload na pagina e mostra todos conteudos de todas `id`

Comment: o que eu quero fazer é ao mudar de pagina ele me exiba somente o conteudo da `id` clicada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema obrigado..

```
//Efeito SliderDown/SliderUp
    $('.sub-menu a').click(function() {

        var anchor;
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        if (link.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
            anchor = '#' + link.split('#').pop();
            console.log('anchor',anchor);
        }

        $('.id-sub').slideUp(2000);
        if (anchor !== undefined) {
            $(anchor).slideDown(2000).addClass('fixed');       
            $('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': $(anchor) }, 600, function(){
                window.location.hash = target;
            })
        }
    });



    //Pre-Loader
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        $('.id-sub').hide();
        $("#loading").fadeOut(2000,function(){
            $("#page").css("display","block").fadeIn("fast-slow");
            var currentPage = window.location.hash;//
            if (currentPage) {
                $(currentPage).slideDown(2000).addClass('fixed');
                $('html,body').animate({ 'scrollTop': $(currentPage).offset().top });
            }
        });


    });
```